# Related rates question - wheat running from a hole at a constant rate to make a cone

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Wheat runs from a hole in a silo at a constant rate and forms a conical heap whose base radius is treble the height. If after 1 minute, the height of the heap is 20 cm, find the rate at which the height is rising at this instant.

And the volume of a cone formula is given.

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

The volume of a cone is

$$V = \frac13 \pi r^2 h$$

where $r$ is the radius of the base, and $h$ is the height.  You then differentiate with respect to time $t$:

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac13 \pi \left (2 r h \frac{dr}{dt} + r^2 \frac{dh}{dt}\right)$$

You know that $r=3 h$, so substitute to get

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac13 \pi  27 h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$$

You need to be given $dV/dt$; then you can solve for $dh/dt$.  In this case,

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac13 \pi (20) (9 \cdot 20^2) \text{cm}^3/\text{min}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $h=h(t)$ be the height at time $t$. Then the base radius is $3h$, and by the usual formula for the volume of a cone, the volume $V$ is given by 
$$V=3\pi h^3.$$
Differentiate, using the Chain Rule. We get 
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=9\pi h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}.$$

If we can find the (constant) value of $\frac{dV}{dt}$ we will be almost finished.

In one minute, $V$ grew from $0$ to $3\pi(20)^3$, so we have $\frac{dV}{dt}=3\pi(20)^3$, and now we have all the information we need.